# How to use htaccess to block IPs in a laravel project dir

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-4

I was under the impression I could use a `.htaccess` file to block IPs to my laravel project `app/views/users/` dir but it doesn't look like its being read. However if I use the directives inside the `public/.htaccess` file it works.

I'm not familiar with `mod_rewrite` so I'm unsure how to block access to `app/views/users` from `public/.htaccess`. Whats the best way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rewrite rule like this in root .htaccess to block any access to `/app/views/users` path:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(110\.174\.129\.147|203\.217\.17\.162|111\.222\.333\.444)$
RewriteRule ^app/views/users(/.*)?$ - [F,NC]
```

Change these IP addresses to whatever addresses you want to block.